# Render HTML from WP API

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm a PHP/WP beginner.

I'm setting up a Paypal server backend using WP REST API endpoints, like this:

```php
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_routes');

function register_routes() {
  $namespace = 'api/v1';

  register_rest_route( $namespace, '/payment_success', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'payment_success',
  ) );
  register_rest_route( $namespace, '/payment_cancelled', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'payment_cancelled',
  ) );
}

function payment_success() {
  $str = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>success</title>
</head>
<body>
  Success!
</body>
</html>
HTML;
  echo $str;
}

function payment_cancelled() {
  $str = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>cancelled</title>
</head>
<body>
  Payment was cancelled.
</body>
</html>
HTML;
  echo $str;
}
```

These HTML responses are to be rendered in a React Native `WebView`, although grabbing the title is all that will be important.

With the code as it is above, the HTML renders with "`null`" appended to the end (because the function returns null after it echos the html). So a browser just prints the html text.

Something tells me this isn't the way I'm supposed to do this. How am I supposed to render HTML from my php? Is there a separate argument to `register_rest_route` to simply render an html file or something like that?

Please help! Thanks!

PS. Why am I using a WP server if I'm not doing this on a WP site? I'm building a React Native app for the a WP site and I've written other custom REST API php on the server. So I want to use the same server for this Paypal code; so I don't have to find a way to shoehorn my requests into whatever API the website is using for its payments.

Comment: Having done this many times from WP to React-Native, I recommend returning JSON and parsing it in react native, rather than trying to render any html.

Comment: The tutorial I read says to use `WebView.props.onNavigationStateChange` to check the title of the new page, to see when the Paypal flow has finished. How would I do that with your recommended method?

Comment: So there's no REST API for this already? I would look into setting up JSON responses which you would return via axios or fetch in react native.

Comment: That's a good idea; I tried setting up `paypal-rest-sdk` in my RN app to handle it all with JS/node in my app, but I was getting an error from its `http` dependency. I see that there is a Paypal REST API but having created a working PHP server integration that uses the key and secret, I'm choosing to not figure out how to get a token for the Paypal request. I'd have to build a whole UI for the Paypal interaction as well, I think.